# My for loop is printing in the wrong order

Tags: python, for-loop, ascii-art

Long story short I'm making an ASCII Art generator and having problems with my loops. It prints the right letters just in the wrong order. My input loop has another loop inside that is supposed to print the 1st line of the artwork based off each letter from the user's input but doesn't print them together if that makes any sense...

I've tried the following loop before and rearranging the statements in the loop, I honestly think I just need a pair of fresh eyes.

In advance I'm very sorry for any grammar, broken syntax talk/not making sense, and missing information. It's my first time using overflow and I haven't touched my IDE in ages. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
boss = input("Text here: ")
for z in range(len(boss)):

    for i in range(6):
        if boss[z] == 'a':
            print(ASCII["a" + str(i)], end='')
        if boss[z] == 'b':
            print(ASCII["b" + str(i)], end='')
        print('')
    z += 1
```

Here is the dict

```
ASCII =  {


"a0" : " █████╗ ",
"a1" : "██╔══██╗",
"a2" : "███████║",
"a3" : "██╔══██║",
"a4" : "██║  ██║",
"a5" : "╚═╝  ╚═╝",


"b0" : "██████╗ ",
"b1" : "██╔══██╗",
"b2" : "██████╔╝",
"b3" : "██╔══██╗",
"b4" : "██████╔╝",
"b5" : "╚═════╝ "

}
```

Input:

```
Text here: ab
```

this is the desired output:

```
█████╗ ██████╗ 
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
███████║██████╔╝
██╔══██║██╔══██╗
██║  ██║██████╔╝
╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═════╝
```

this is what I'm getting back:

```
█████╗ 
██╔══██╗
███████║
██╔══██║
██║  ██║
╚═╝  ╚═╝
██████╗ 
██╔══██╗
██████╔╝
██╔══██╗
██████╔╝
╚═════╝
```

Just for reference, it is **very** important that it prints like this:

a0 + b0

print('')

a1 + b1

print('')

a2 + b2

```
 █████╗ ██████╗ 
then
 █████╗ ██████╗ 
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
then
 █████╗ ██████╗ 
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
███████║██████╔╝
etc.
```

Comment: You must combine individual lines, not letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop should iterate over the lines of the image, and the inner over letters in the input string:

```
ASCII =  {

"a0" : " █████╗ ",
"a1" : "██╔══██╗",
"a2" : "███████║",
"a3" : "██╔══██║",
"a4" : "██║  ██║",
"a5" : "╚═╝  ╚═╝",


"b0" : "██████╗ ",
"b1" : "██╔══██╗",
"b2" : "██████╔╝",
"b3" : "██╔══██╗",
"b4" : "██████╔╝",
"b5" : "╚═════╝ "

}

boss = "abba"
for i in range(6):
    for x in boss:
        print(ASCII[x + str(i)], end='')
    print('')
```

This prints:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  You also saved me a bunch of time, my original idea was to write a bunch of if statements lo